# Prove $f$ is unique

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A$ be a simply connected region in $\mathbb{C}$

Let $\Delta=\{z : |z|\lt 1 \}$ 
Prove that if $f$ is a conformal and bijective map, so that it sends a point $z_0 \in A$ to the origin and $f'(z_0 )\gt 0$ , then $f$ is unique.

Any hints on how to prove this? I'm new to complex analyisis (using Marsden's Book) and I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Let $g:A\to \Delta$ be another function which satisfies this property.

Then 
$h:=g\circ f^{-1}:\Delta\to \Delta$ is a conformal and bijective map such that $h(0)=0$ and  $h'(0)=g'(z_0)/f'(z_0)>0$.
Then use [Schwarz Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma).